# Why might it be important to specify a family when using GEE if it doesn't make any assumption about the joint distribution?

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations, joint-distribution

I understand that one of the advantages of GEE is that you make no assumptions about the joint probability distribution, relying instead on the mean, the variance and the associations (corr). Why then do we specify a family in the command for `gee`?

```
model <- geeglm(y~x, data=data, id=id, family=gaussian('identity'), corstr='ar1')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although a joint distribution is not assumed, a marginal distribution *is* assumed, which determines the variance function. This variance function describes how the variance depends on the mean, which is determined by the family (gaussian, poisson..etc).